# crossrider firefox appAPI.message.toActiveTab

Tags: firefox, crossrider

For my extension I want to check if a certain set of websites is visited. Only the first time these sites are visited I want to call a function. So, my extension.js checks if one of these websites is visited, background.js keeps track of the amount of visits and calls a function in extension.js in case of the first visit. This works fine except in Firefox. It seems that the addListener is not called at all. Any idea why?

Extension.js

```
// check if site is visited
var websites= ['facebook.com', 'site.com', 'anothersite.com'
for (i = 0; i < websites.length; i++) { 
    if (appAPI.matchPages("*" + websites[i] + "*")) {
        // count visit
        appAPI.message.toBackground({type:'update', data:i});
    }    
}

appAPI.message.addListener(function(msg) {
    if (msg.type == 'testf') {
        // not executed (in Firefox)
    }
});
```

Background.js

```
appAPI.message.addListener(function(msg) {
    if (msg.type == 'update') {
        i = msg.data;
        if (visited[i] == 0) { 
            // call function when visited first time
            appAPI.message.toActiveTab({type:'testf'});
        }
        visited[i] ++;
    }
});
```

Comment: In general, the [appAPI.message](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.message) API works correctly in Firefox and without seeing the rest of your code, I can see there is a typo in _extension.js_: `if (appAPI.matchPages("*" + webshops[i] + "*"))`; if I'm not mistaken, it should be **websites[i]**. Also, in the _background.js_ file, I presume you have pre-populated the variable **visited**; if not, `if (visited[i] == 0)` may cause an error. [**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: I tried to clean up the code to make my question more comprehensible, sorry for the typo (now edited). I also pre-populate the variable visited in my code. As I said, it all works perfectly in Chrome and IE, but not in Firefox. It counts the number of visits, but it seems that it does not send a message to the active tab when the website is visited for the first time. Maybe because of the complex construction?

However, I now use the 'Page Impression' plugin to sort of retrieve the same information :). Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: So you no longer use the toActiveTab method and hence this matter is resolved? If this is not the case, provide the extension id and I'm happy to test and investigate.